# Haskell cannot match expected type 'Bool' to type [t0]

Tags: haskell, types, ghc

New to haskell and I keep running into this cryptic error when I try to pattern match a non empty list

Code:

```
type Bits = [Bool]

nor :: Bits -> Bits -> Bits
nor [] [_:__] = error "mismatched length"
nor [_:__] [] = error "mismatched length"
nor [] [] = []
nor (x:xs) (y:ys) = (norBit x y):nor xs ys
    where norBit x y = if x == True || y == True then False else True

main = do
    print (nor [True] [False])
```

Error:

```
gates.hs:4:9:
Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘[t0]’
In the pattern: _ : __
In the pattern: [_ : __]
In an equation for ‘nor’: nor [] [_ : __] = []
```

Comment: A common mistake: the list constructors are `[]` and `(:)` (with *round brackets*), actually the brackets are not always necessary, but using square ones, is not an option.

Comment: `if x == True || y == True then False else True` --> `not (x || y)`.

Comment: I didn't want to use the built in not, as i'm going to build a not with this nor later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list constructors in Haskell are `[]` and `(x:xs)`, note that the second constructor uses *round* brackets.

If you write `[_:__]`, then that is valid syntax as well: since Haskell thinks you write a pattern `[(x:xs)]`, so a *singleton* list, where the *first* element matches the `(x:xs)` pattern. But that should mean that the type is an `[[a]]`, instead of an `[a]`, and since a `Bool` is *not* a type alias for a list type, the problem can not be resolved.

You can fix the situation here by writing *round brackets*:

```
nor :: Bits -> Bits -> Bits
nor [] (_:_) = error "mismatched length"
nor (_:_) [] = error "mismatched length"
nor [] [] = []
nor (x:xs) (y:ys) = (norBit x y):nor xs ys
    where norBit x y = if x == True || y == True then False else True
```

Or we can rewrite the function to:

```
nor :: Bits -> Bits -> Bits
nor (x:xs) (y:ys) = not (x || y) : nor xs ys
nor [] [] = []
nor _ _ = error "mismatched length"
```

Note that due to laziness, in case you for example `take k` of the result, with `k` smaller than the length of *both* lists, it will *not* raise an error.

Comment: Why would the last line catch errors in this case? And yes I knew I could make the norBit a little simpler, but I did not want to use the built in not function

Comment: Because `_` is a wildcard. Now the first two lines catch the cases where either both lists are empty, or both lists are non-empty. So the *remaining* cases are the ones where the first list is empty and the right one is non-empty, or vice versa.

Comment: I see, Thanks a lot!